# Shouldn't `return Health.down().build();` by default return 503 code response status in custom actuator endpoint?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

- Spring boot version: 2.7.4
- Link to sample [project](https://github.com/hrvojet/spring-health-down)

When creating custom actuator endpoint and returning **DOWN** status with *Health.Builder*, HTTP response status code is **200** but **503** is expected.
I have created simple project which, upon running and making a request to *http://localhost:8080/actuator/custom* resolves:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/actuator/custom
200
5 ms
GET /actuator/custom HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 14 Oct 2022 11:00:59 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
 
{"status":"DOWN"}
```

Why `return Health.down().build();` doesn't return 503 code response status by default and how can I make it return 503 (or any other arbitrary response status)?

Comment: Something like this:  return Health.down().withDetail("Error Code", errorCode).build(); ? Also check this part in the reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.4/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.health.writing-custom-health-indicators

Comment: It returns 200 because the call of the actuator was successfull. The status  "down" is only in the returned json

Comment: @Jens I get that, so I should wrap the response in ResponseEntity and set the status from there?

Comment: It depends what you trying to archive